# How to get the ViewController from UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift

When a user taps on an item, I want to get the ViewController associated with that tab.

The TabBar delegate no longer provides the ViewController delegate. Instead, it provides a `didSelectItem` delegate.

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
}
```

How do I get the ViewController from `UITabBarItem`?

Comment: Just drag a tab bar controller onto the storyboard. Once you do that, you can configure the tabs by dragging from the Tab Bar Controller to your storyboard that you've got associated w/ your view controllers. If you want to alter the order of the tabs, you can drag the tabs around on the tabBarController to reorder them. There's really no reason you need to monkey with code setting up the tabBarController unless you're going to move around programatically between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a `UITabBarController` and not just a `UITabBar` look into using `UITabBarControllerDelegate` rather than `UITabBarDelegate`. `UITabBarControllerDelegate` provides the method:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
    didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a **swift 4** Extension version that works for me:

```
import UIKit

extension UIApplication {

var visibleViewController: UIViewController? {

    guard let rootViewController = keyWindow?.rootViewController else {
        return nil
    }

    return getVisibleViewController(rootViewController)
}

private func getVisibleViewController(_ rootViewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController {
        return getVisibleViewController(presentedViewController)
    }

    if let navigationController = rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
        return navigationController.visibleViewController
    }

    if let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        // Uncomment the line bellow the TabBarController
        //return tabBarController.selectedViewController

        // uncomment the line bellow to get the visible ViewController of the TabBarController
        return getVisibleViewController(tabBarController.selectedViewController!)
    }

    return rootViewController
  }
}
```

This can be called as easy as this:

```
let visibleVC = UIApplication.shared.visibleViewController
```

I hope this work for you as well ;)